# How to import pypdf2?

Tags: python, pypdf

I have gone through terminal and wrote pip install pypdf2. But when I wrote import pypdf2 the problem says import pypdf2 could not be resolved pylance(reportMissingImports)

Comment: Which OS ? Pip version ? Python version ? Please  Show Your code ;-) Do not be shy :-D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.